# How to remove default header in native react Drawer?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have tried {header: null} and {headerMode: null} but those are not working. Can anyone provide solution for removing default header in native react drawer. The above mentioned are working for stack navigator but those are working for react native react Drawer.

Comment: Can you please post code of how you created your router?